# Vimeo URL I've never seen before with two different IDS. How do I get it to work with one?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have this Vimeo URL.

https://vimeo.com/192207770/0faf1dd09d

I don't understand what the two IDS represent and how I can shorten it into a single ID URL.

All other vimeo URLs I've seen are `vimeo.com/<id>`

What do these two IDS signify in this order? Where is the unique video ID I can address with `vimeo.com/<id>`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That URL is an unlisted video. Unlisted videos are only playable by viewers with the full URL (`https://vimeo.com/[video_id]/[unlisted_hash]`) and are not returned in Vimeo search results.

Video privacy settings are outlined here: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224817847-Privacy-settings-overview

In general, an unlisted video will have a uri like this:

```
"uri":"/[video_id]:[unlisted_hash]"
```

However, it's best practice to get that uri from the API, instead of building it yourself. You can get the video's uri and metadata by making this request:

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos?links=https://vimeo.com/[video_id]/[unlisted_hash]
```

Finally, for unlisted videos you must have the `unlisted_hash` to get its metadata or to view it on vimeo.com. For an unlisted video with the url `https://vimeo.com/1234567/abcde`, both vimeo.com and the API will return 404 for `https://vimeo.com/1234567`.

I hope this information helps!

Comment: Thanks. that helps me understand the origin of this issue so that I can deal with it. It would appear Vimeo's JS API player doesn't support unlisted videos, even when the video ID includes the "video_id/hash". Now that I can put a name on this kind of URL, I'll be closer to resolving this.

Comment: Is it possible to get the hash id from the vimeo API, or can you only get it when you visit the user account page on vimeo?

Comment: If you don't know that unlisted hash, you can only get it if you are the video owner (and thus, from the video's settings page on vimeo.com)

Comment: This answer doesnt work with all URL https://vimeo.com/477957994?unlisted_hash=2282452868

Comment: Vimeo might have changed the path/format of unlisted video URLs. I'm no longer with the company so I don't have a recommendation, try contacting their support: https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to note that in my case when using an unlisted video, I simply omitted the last segment of that url when sending a videoID to my player SDK.

In your case it would simply be the video id of 192207770